# A way to add specific sound file at the end of a phrase?

Tags: vst

I'm using Audiomulch along with some VSTs to simulate VHF communication in Real Time. I would like to add a sound of a PTT (Push-to-talk) button when it's released and i would like it to be played automatically when it detects someone cease speaking (condition 1 sec silence). Is there a VST or other way that could be accomplished? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you create the following kind of construction in Audiomulch?

```
while(thereIsInputSignal):
    If volume has been below x level for 1 sec:
        then play ptt.wav.
```

If not, then creating such VST wouldn't be too difficult (for someone who's done VSTs before) although an easier path could be to create a patch in Pure Data and then load it as VST using Camomile.

If it's not for real-time use, then you could merely process the entire sound file "offline" so that you generate another sound file with "ptt.wav" played in the spots where you recognized 1 sec or more of silence.

A manual solution would of course be to load the ptt.wav into a sampler and then listen through the track and record yourself playing that sound back whenever you think it should play.

Comment: Many, many thanks for your explanations. Could you elaborate on how to create the data needed for Comomile, please? I have no experience in creating VSTs, so i guess Camomile is the way to go.

Comment: @Potni There are lots of tutorials for Pure Data (which I would recommend to take a look at for other purposes as well, not just this particular). You need to be able to load two sound files and then read through the other and then create the logic for playing the other based on the first one's duration and level. This can be done in any programming language, but I understand it's complicated for a novice. I'm a bit busy although I can take a look if I could provide you with either a Pure Data patch of perhaps a Python script.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm taking the plunge and will try to patch it on my own. Many thanks for your time. I'll post updates ;)